# VBSCRIPT Instagram autologin failing

Tags: vbscript, automation, instagram, form-submit, autologin

Trying to create a simple script to autologin to my instagram account.  Upon submitting the form (programmatically clicking login button), the username and password fields clear and login fails.  Any way around this?  Thanks in advance.

```
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

'Login
IE.Visible = true
IE.Navigate "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: WScript.Sleep 100: Loop 

for each a in ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")
    if a.name = "username" then
        a.value = "myusername" '<=== Enter user name here
    end if
next


for each b in ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")
    if b.name = "password" then
        b.value = "my password" '<===== Enter password here
    end if
next

wscript.sleep 1000

for each btn in ie.document.getelementsbytagname("button")
    if btn.innertext = "Log in" or btn.getAttribute("class") = "_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0" then
        btn.click
    end if
next

'IE.document.Forms(0).Submit
```

Comment: I've also tried using a.focus and a.blur, but blur also wipes the value entry.